# Can you use the Distant Strike from Horizon Walker to get in melee range and attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, ranger, teleportation

Suppose a Horizon Walker Ranger is not in melee range and has used all their movement. Can a they make a melee attack, and use their Distant Strike ability before the attack, get to melee range and finish the attack?

Comment: Are you worried specifically whether it's legal to declare a melee attack when you're not currently in range? For example, maybe the ability only allows you to teleport to the other side of an enemy you're already next to?

Comment: exactly.
The phb texts says:

Making an Attack
Choose a target. Pick a target within your attack's range: a creature, an object, or a location.

Since the creature is not in your range when you make the attack,how can you make the attack action against that creature?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Yes

The text of the ability is:

> At 11th level, you gain the ability to pass between the planes in a blink of an eye. When you use the Attack action, you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see.

and, yes, this means you can use the Attack action when you're not in melee range of an opponent, and then teleport to melee range before making your attack(s).

Note that "taking the attack action" is different from "making an attack".  Rules text:

> ## Attack
>
> With this action, you make one melee or ranged attack. See the “Making an Attack” section for the rules that govern attacks.
>
> Certain features, such as the Extra Attack feature of the Fighter, allow you to make more than one attack with this action.

So, first you declare that you're taking the "attack action", and then you teleport, and then you resolve "making an attack" which includes choosing your targets.